# Create a data set for keras model.fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have two lists and a Keras model

```
inputs  = [NumPyArrIn_1,...,NumPyArrIn_n]   # each NumPyArrIn_i is an input
targets = [NumPyArrTar_1,...,NumPyArrTar_N] # each NumPyArrTar_i is a target 
                                            # NumPyArrIn_i
```

The model has a **single** input. `inputs` represent my data set. In other words, each epoch will run over the `inputs` list.
I wish to train my model by calling to `model.fit`.
As far as I understood from the documentation I can train the model in the following manner:

```
    model.fit(x=inputs, 
              y=targets, 
              steps_per_epoch = n, 
              callbacks=callbacks,
              epochs=1,
              shuffle=False)
```

The following error observed when I tried to run it:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your 
model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['Logits'] but 
instead got the following list of 50 arrays: [array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
```

Is doesn't expect to get a list of inputs and another list of targets.
The following line works properly:

```
    model.fit(x=inputs[0], 
              y=targets[0], 
              steps_per_epoch = n, 
              callbacks=callbacks,
              epochs=1,
              shuffle=False)
```

**What is the right way to pass the data set?**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following approach (please note the "introduction" of the shape in line 13 by using "," but nothing after that before ")":

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

number_of_cases=100
number_of_features_in=70
number_of_features_out=55

inputs=np.random.rand(number_of_cases,number_of_features_in)
targets=np.random.rand(number_of_cases,number_of_features_out)

input_for_model=keras.Input(shape=(number_of_features_in,))

one_layer_of_network=layers.Dense(1)

output_from_model=one_layer_of_network(input_for_model)

model=keras.Model(inputs=input_for_model,outputs=output_from_model)

model.compile(loss='MeanSquaredError',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

n=1

model.fit(x=inputs,
              y=targets,
              steps_per_epoch = n,
              epochs=1,
              shuffle=False)

model.summary()
```

Comment: My model has a single input. I want to iterate over the inputs.

Comment: In your "solution language"; what is the function of the model? Are you finding mapping between [1] ---> [23] or [1,22] ---> [123] or [1,2,3,4] ----> [12,3,2], please clarify to be better able to understand the problem.

Comment: inputs list is my data set. Each member is a sample, an input to a single iteration of the NN. targets[i] is the target of inputs[i]. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: Change number_of_features_in=1 and number_of_features_out=1 and then you have a NN "from one number to one number" mapping. And then; write  test_output=model(tf.random.uniform((55,1))) and see the test_output.shape results in a tensor having a shape of [55,1]. Meaning you input 55 separate samples in and get 55 separate samples out. Does this "tensor-strucure" -thinking gives an answer for your question?

Comment: I think that I understand. The input tensor includes all samples. So I have to create a single inputs tensor and a single target tensor.  steps_per_epoch will split it to batches.